# Handling Paged results in cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise

I am looking at [this](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html) . But not able to figure out how it works. My expectation was when I will do `session_execute` it will give me `10` rows `fetch_size=10`.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users where region_code=1"
statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=10)
for user_row in session.execute(statement):
    print(user_row)
    print('*'*100)
```

Its giving me single rows only. What I am missing here. I want to make it a `paginated api`

Answer (score 1):

if you use `SELECT * FROM users where region_code=1 LIMIT 10` it will fetch 10 records. if you use `SELECT * FROM users where region_code=1` with a fetch size of 10, it will page through all the matching rows grabbing 10 at a time. After your for loop consumes 10 rows it will make another blocking query to get the next 10 automatically.

Comment: Got it my `results.current_rows` is giving me 10 rows `(fetch_size)`. I am also using `paging_state` to get the next set. But I have a doubt if user jumps from page `1` to `5` then this is not the right way correct?

Comment: Also if a user want to backtrack page 4 to 3 , it will not work here right?